# Missing geometry type and SRID in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, srid, geometry-data-type

I created a view with

```sql
select a, st_union(geom)
from table
group by a
```

srid: 25832, geometry type: Multipolygon

The view has no SRID and the geometry type is `"GEOMETRY"`.

Now i want to calculate the area with the geometry in the view. Because of the missing SRID the results are not correct. How can i set the SRID and geometry type for the gemoetries for the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to **explicitly cast** the calculated geometries as the correct type, **including their *typemods***, or PostgreSQL will not register the *typemods* in the *View*:

```
SELECT a,
       ST_Union(geom)::GEOMETRY(MULTIPOLYGON, 25832) AS geom
FROM   <table>
GROUP BY
       a
;
```

Note that this will fail if the calculated geometries do not match fully with the type definition!

Comment: I'm curious if you have intuition as to why this is the case. Why doesn't the SRID of the original geometry (assuming it is set) propagate to the VIEW?

Comment: @amball PostgreSQL doesn't have a clue that there may be a link between the source type and this 100% newly created piece of data; it only knows that `ST_Union` returns a (generic) `GEOMETRY` type.

Comment: But normally PostgreSQL seems to retain the SRID. E.g. `SELECT ST_SRID(ST_Union(geom)) FROM mytable;` returns the original SRID. Is this something particular to a VIEW?

Comment: @amball indeed, *the actual information* is stored per instance of and in the type itself (no loss of information)! However, the crucial part is where these are defined as type specific constraints via the *type-modifiers*: for e.g. DDL on the relations, these *relation attributes* are followed across the system tables `pg_class` and `pg_attributes`, but PostgreSQL *does not* follow these when handled as *function parameters* (and this includes all operators, as they are implemented as functions), meaning that they are checked when passed to a function, but not retained in the process.

Comment: thanks for the detailed clarification!

Answer (score 1):

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html

ST_SetSRID and ST_Multi:

```
select a, st_setsrid(st_multi(st_union(geom)), 25832) from table group by a
```

Answer (score 1):

I got to mix the statements:

```
select a, 
st_multi(ST_Union(geom))::GEOMETRY(MULTIPOLYGON, 25832) 
as geom from table GROUP BY  a
```

Best Regards